# Asymmetric Encryption

Tags: security, encryption

If a public key is used to encrypt the private key, and the public key is known to everyone, what is stopping a hacker from intercepting the private key, then using the public key to decrypt it and then using the private key to decrypt and encoded message?

Comment: Public and private keys are generated separately.  You keep the private key and never reveal it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming or software development. It is much better suited for [security.se]. It is also unclear what the system architecture and communication flow might be.

Comment: "what is stopping a hacker from intercepting the private key", well you keep the private keep private!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way public/private key crypto works is that anyone can use the public key to encrypt a piece of data, but you need the private key (which the owner does not distribute) in order to decrypt that data.

It doesn't matter that the data being encrypted is the private key itself.

Comment: yeah i just saw the definition here :). im studying for my comp test and my textbook doesnt give a proper definition. thanks.

Comment: @s-mo Glad I could help. Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.